# Filter and aggregate based on other dataframe

Tags: python, python-polars

Say I have

```py
df1 = pl.DataFrame({'start': [1., 2., 4.], 'end': [2, 4., 6]})
df2 = pl.DataFrame({'idx': [1, 1.7, 2.3, 2.5, 3., 4], 'values': [3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 5]})
```

They look like this:

```py
In [8]: df1
Out[8]:
shape: (3, 2)
┌───────┬─────┐
│ start ┆ end │
│ ---   ┆ --- │
│ f64   ┆ f64 │
╞═══════╪═════╡
│ 1.0   ┆ 2.0 │
│ 2.0   ┆ 4.0 │
│ 4.0   ┆ 6.0 │
└───────┴─────┘

In [9]: df2
Out[9]:
shape: (6, 2)
┌─────┬────────┐
│ idx ┆ values │
│ --- ┆ ---    │
│ f64 ┆ i64    │
╞═════╪════════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ 3      │
│ 1.7 ┆ 1      │
│ 2.3 ┆ 4      │
│ 2.5 ┆ 2      │
│ 3.0 ┆ 3      │
│ 4.0 ┆ 5      │
└─────┴────────┘
```

I would like to end up with something like this:

```py
In [6]: expected = pl.DataFrame({
   ...:     'start': [1., 2., 4.],
   ...:     'end': [2., 4.5, 6.],
   ...:     'sum_values': [4, 9, 5]
   ...: })

In [7]: expected
Out[7]:
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────┬─────┬────────────┐
│ start ┆ end ┆ sum_values │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---        │
│ f64   ┆ f64 ┆ i64        │
╞═══════╪═════╪════════════╡
│ 1.0   ┆ 2.0 ┆ 4          │
│ 2.0   ┆ 4.5 ┆ 9          │
│ 4.0   ┆ 6.0 ┆ 5          │
└───────┴─────┴────────────┘
```

Here's an inefficient way of doing it I came up with, using `apply`:

```py
(
    df1.with_columns(
        df1.apply(
            lambda row: df2.filter(
                pl.col("idx").is_between(row[0], row[1], closed="left")
            )["values"].sum()
        )["apply"].alias("sum_values")
    )
)
```

It gives the correct output, but because it uses `apply` and a Python lambda function, it's not as performant as it could be.

Is there a way to write this using polars native expressions API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is another way apart from a cross join:

```
(df1.join(df2, how='cross')
    .filter(pl.col('idx').is_between('start', 'end', closed='left'))
    .groupby('start', 'end')
    .sum()
)
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌───────┬─────┬─────┬────────┐
│ start ┆ end ┆ idx ┆ values │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---    │
│ f64   ┆ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ i64    │
╞═══════╪═════╪═════╪════════╡
│ 4.0   ┆ 6.0 ┆ 4.0 ┆ 5      │
│ 1.0   ┆ 2.0 ┆ 2.7 ┆ 4      │
│ 2.0   ┆ 4.0 ┆ 7.8 ┆ 9      │
└───────┴─────┴─────┴────────┘
```